# Eating my toasts before work

Tags: time, find-the-order

I work remotely as a software engineer, and because I like sleeping as much as possible I always leave my alarm clock set to the last possible minute. Problem is, today I did not hear my alarm go off, and so I started working 2 hours later than I should have and I didn't eat. Because I have a meeting just 11 minutes from now, and I can't communicate well without eating my 6 morning toasts, I need to start toasting bread right away. My toaster, which is not electric, can only hold 4 slices of bread at a time and I have to toast slices one side at a time, and each side of a slice takes 3 minutes to toast. Can I make it in time, given that I have already sliced the bread and have everything in place, even if I have to eat them during the meeting? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Name the six slices A through F. Toast A through D for three minutes. Then toast C through F for three minutes, making sure to first flip C and D. Finally, toast A, B, E, and F for three minutes, making sure to first flip them.